# How strong an electric field is needed to violate electrostatic equilibrium of usual conductor?

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, maxwell-equations, conductors, equilibrium

As is told by almost all textbooks, a conductor reach electrostatic equilibrium in an elctric field.
My quetion is that, is there any kind of conductor, which has so few electrons and eletron-like charges to reach electrostatic equilibrium?
Or in other words, for usual conductor, how strong the exterior electric field we need to to violate electrostatic equilibrium. Is that possible if we could be able to create such strong electric field.

Answer (score 0):

For an object in an electric field, one of three things can happen.  1. The free charges relocate to a new equilibrium condition in such a way that there is no field inside.  2. There are no free charges, and the molecules of the object polarize and 3. (your case) there are not enough free charges to cancel the field, and the molecules of the object polarize.  #1 is a conductor, #2 is an insulator, and #3 is a semiconductor.   So while such objects exist, we don't call them conductors.

Comment: Thanks your answer. However, I just want to know electrostatic equilibrium limit of a tipical conductor. I've got a simple idea.  Idealy, we can guess number of free electical charges in a conductor, then thier fields are superposed to give a course estimation of exterior filed that can violate the  electrostatic equilibrium.  The key is how to superpose these fields. The simplest way is sum them together as sclar. However, electrical filed is a vector. So need a reasonble model of distriubtion of electricities. Or some new phenomenology maybe spring up in such strong electric field.